How connect to an Oracle database from ASP.NET Core by database first - I am trying many ways Scaffold-DbContext In all its forms not working
I have been trying many ways to run Scaffold-DbContext In all its forms - but nothing is working.
Oracle:
Install-Package Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core


Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb)));User ID=hr;Password=hr;Persist Security Info=True" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore  -OutputDir Models -Force


Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<data source>" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models  


First one looks correct of SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb is right. Which error do you have? Have you used this reference https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/ ?

Here's a case which using a command similar to yours and that command worked well...How about try with -Tables TABLE1 parameter?
